# Computer keeps crashing, need help troubleshooting

Tags: windows-10, cpu, motherboard, crash, desktop-computer

My desktop PC started crashing two days ago and keeps on doing it.

When it does, there is no error message, no bluescreen, nothing. Sometimes video just freezes and sound keeps playing for some time before quitting as well. Sometimes the screen just goes black. Also, it happened when the system was idle, or when browsing, watching youtube, things like that.

There is no apparent change, that might be the cause of it, there were no hardware changes, no new software and no updates, at least none that I'm aware of.

First thing I thought about were temperatures, so I kept monitoring them. Because the PC seems to be prone to crashing again, My CPU temps are regularly below 50°C with the fan spinning around 1400 RPM. GPU temps were low as well, around 40°C with slow fan when idle.

I then entered the BIOS to look at temps and settings there. Temps were low there as well (MB temp below 30°C, CPU again around or below 50°) and there were no apparent wrong settings. I didn't make any changes there before it started happening.

Right now however, it crashed the second time already, when I was still in BIOS, which makes me think this is no problem with the OS but a hardware problem. I really don't know however, how I might figure out which of the components might be causing it. Help is greatly appreciated!

PC specs:
ASRock Z170 Pro4S Version P3.30
Intel i7 6700K (not overclocked)
One large be quiet! CPU cooler that I don't remember the exact name right now
Gigabyte Aorus 1080TI Extreme Edition (again, not overclocked)
2 x 8GB G.Skill F4-2400C15D-16GRR RAM
be quiet! Pure Power 9 700W power supply
Windows 10 1909

Comment: I'm just trying to guess, but since there are no messages or blue screen errors, it seems like a power supply problem

Comment: It also sounds to me like the PSU dropping out - OP, try and test with another PSU if you have one to see if the problem remains (testing with a known, good, reputable PSU)

Comment: I hear fingers pointed at the PSU so many times in posts like this. I don’t know why because it is literally the least likely thing to be a problem. From thousands of computers I’ve worked on over decades I can’t think of a single situation where the PSU did anything other than work or not work. Never did it cause random lock ups. Take the computer apart, check all the connections. **Remove and reseat the RAM**.  Bad connections happen over time. They are easily solved while booting Memtest and tapping on components and wires until they are found and things are solid and no longer lock up.

Comment: @Appleoddity I'm not sure about the last part. Would I run memtest and tap on things, cables, check connections etc? Meaning when the PC locks up, I found the bad one?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. The same thing can be done while running a bootable disk test like HDD Regenerator, to check if the drive and connections are stable. But in this case it doesn’t sound like a disk issue. RAM is extremely likely. Also clean the case all out and physically check the temp of other components like other heat sinks on the motherboard. Not all component temps are monitored but can still overheat. A physical inspection for bulging or leaking capacitors on the motherboard is also good, but this seems to be less of an issue nowadays.

Comment: @Appleoddity Alright, makes sense. Thanks so far. Gonna do it right away, when I come back after christmas. Also thanks to everyone else sharing their thoughts. Happy Holidays